# How to identify android app installations

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier

I am working on android app,which contains license content,i want to restrict devices based on license for that i need to identify unique android devices using id,i found some ways to find unique device using  macaddress,serial no,android_id but every id has some fallback

Comment: will you store in play store

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: You can use UUID.

Comment: @AyushBansal i read that question but every id has some fallback

Comment: That is the best answer to the question.  I suggest if you really need to restrict it, restrict to a user account authorized by username and password rather than device.  Device is to trivial to fake no matter what you do.